# How to add a newline in string smtpjs

Tags: javascript, smtp, newline, smtpjs

Im trying to make newlines in the body of the SMTPJS

```
        Email.send({
        Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        Username : "adventureboots.manager@gmail.com",
        Password : "gabriela2600",
        
        To : "bernardoolisan@gmail.com",
        From : "adventureboots.manager@gmail.com",
        Subject : "Compra AdventureBoots de " + name + " " + apellido,
        Body : "ADVENTUREBOOTS!\n" + name + " " + apellido + "\nDATOS DE DISEÑO" + "\nModelo | " + modelo +"\nTalla | " + talla + "\nColor | " + color + "\nColor De Costuras | " + color_de_costura + "\nMaterial | " + material + "\nDATOS DE DIRECCION" + "\nDirección | " + direccion + "\nLugar | " + vivienda + "\nCiudad | " + ciudad + "\nCodigo Postal | " + codigo_postal + "\nCONTACTO" + "\nTelefono | " + telefono + "\nEmail | " + email
    })
```

when i saw the mail \n is not working, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could try with HTML with the br tag (***this is what it works in the OP***):

```
<br>
```

or, in JS we could use the template literals (also called Template strings).

```
`some text ${aVariable} some other text`
```

Even if it doesn't work, the string assigned to the body property would look much cleaner.

```
const obj = {Body : `ADVENTUREBOOTS!
${name} ${apellido}
DATOS DE DISEÑO
Modelo ${modelo}
Talla ${talla}`};
```

JS Snippet:

```js
    const name = "John";
    const apellido = "Green"
    
    const obj = {Body : `ADVENTUREBOOTS!
    ${name} ${apellido} ...`};
    
    console.log(obj);
```

Since we are using SMTP, if the solutions above are not working, you might need to create a string according to the [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt):
Spec 2.3.7:

> "[message data] Lines consist of zero or more *data characters* terminated by >the sequence ASCII character "CR" (hex value0D) followed immediately by ASCII >character "LF" (hex value 0A).

[ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: lol ok, but that is HTML tho. Shall we add it to the answer for the guys who might have the same issue?

Comment: yes Add it so i can give u a correct answer

Comment: too kind, you did solve it by yourself! Sorry that I couldn't really help

Comment: just change it with the <br>, you try to help so im going to give it correct